# apache2 redirect doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, https, apache2

This is my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://example.com/
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

It should redirect user to https://example.com, but it doesn't work. I have this configuration for more than year, it worked, but now when I try to visit http://example.com, its display following error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

When I type http://www.example.com, apache redirects request properly. Any other redirect to different virtual host works properly too. I'm using Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 1):

You could try out a different order as mentioned below, besides that it seems your redirect is a permanent one, so you could let search engines know about that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

While we're at it, a common thing to forget is a redirection of https://example.com to https://www.example.com if being standard conform or vice versa if you prefere the domain without www as the main one.